# How to disable remote cache completely for all bazel rules?

Tags: bazel

My network is very very very slow. I do not want to use Remote cache.
Is there any flag to prevent using remote cache?

Answer (score 9):

"--noremote_accept_cached" option seem to work for me

Answer (score 1):

Look in your `.bazelrc` file for `--remote_cache`

```
build --remote_cache=http://replace-with-your.host:port
```

Comment it out!

`--remote_cache` defines the URL of the remote cache server. If it does not exist no remote cache is used

Comment: Downvoted because unclear answer. How would this prevent remote caching?